# Django missed slash in url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created a url like 'api/personal/'. Everything went right when I did local test using './manage.py runserver'. But when I used factoryboy to create a client and try to get the detail by 'self.user_client.get('api/personal/')', the response showed 404 NOTFOUND because the url had changed to apipersonal/. Does anyone know why did it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [named](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) urls for avoiding this kind of confusions. Define the url like this:

```
 path('api/personal/', your_view, name='api_personal')  # added keyword argument name
```

and use it in the tests with [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) like this:

```
 self.client.get(reverse('api_personal'))
```

Comment: I have tried like that: url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', PersonalDetailView.as_view(),
        name='user_detail'), but I got: "Reverse for 'user_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/personal/(?P<user_id>\\d+)/$']"

Comment: Ah, you need to call `reverse('user_detail', args=[user_id])`, where user_id is the id/pk of your user.(ie: `user.id`)

Comment: Solved! Thank you!